# Pass user ID from a list, from one page to another

Tags: php

I have a table that lists the users of the database. Each row contains a button that it takes you to a form that you can modify the users details. To do so I have to get the user ID from the button and pass it over to the modification page.

```
<?php

                while ($user=mysql_fetch_assoc($records)) {

                    echo "<tr>";

                    echo "<td>".$user['user_id']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$user['name']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$user['surname']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$user['email']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$user['dob']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$user['country']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$user['privillage']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$user['active']."</td>";
                    echo "<form action='modify_user.php' method='POST'>";
                    echo "<td><input type='submit' name='".$user['user_id']."' value='modify' /></td>";
                    echo "</form>";                 

                    echo "</tr>";
                }

                mysql_close();
            ?>
```

$user['user_id'] is the variable that I need to pass over.

Then on the other page I have

```
<?php

session_start();

$regValue = $_GET[$user['user_id']];

echo "Your user ID is: ".$regValue.".";

?>
```

I know something is missing, but I cant figure it out. Could you give me any hints how to solve this issue please?

Comment: You don't see a problem trying to use the user ID to get the user ID?

Comment: should be just $regValue = $_GET['user_id'];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to pass argument via GET, you need to do something like this:

```
echo "<form action='modify_user.php?user_id=" . $user['user_id'] . "' method='POST'>";
echo "<td><input type='submit' value='modify' /></td>";
echo "</form>";
```

in modify_user.php you will be able to get:

```
$regValue = intval($_GET['user_id']);
```

Comment: Thanks Lashane. It works. I was making things in my mind more complex than it is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a button instead of an input

```
echo "<td>
        <button type='submit' name='user_id' value='".$user['user_id']."'>modify</button>
     </td>";
```

Then on your other page you can get the user_id from $_POST

```
$regValue = $_POST['user_id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass the `user_id` via POST request then instead of `$regValue = $_GET[$user['user_id']];` do this:

```
<?php

    session_start();

    $regValue = key($_POST);

    echo "Your user ID is: " . $regValue;

?>
```

Here's the reference:

- [`key()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.key.php)